# several authors for the same git commit?

Tags: linux, git

Let's suppose that I am working in a pair programming mode, so two persons (Alex and me Basile) sitting in front of the same screen. So when we decide to `git commit` some new patch, we really are two authors of it.

Is it possible to `git commit`  with both Alex & Basile as authors of the *same* commit? How?

(if that matters, it is on Linux/Debian, on the command line, with a recent `git version 2.18.0`)

The man page of `git commit` mentions a `--author=<author>` option, but I understand that there is still only one author possible.

Comment: In git itself? No. But third party tools like git pair, git duet and GitHub's own functionality offer various workarounds with various trade offs.